# Overloading Images

Tags: qt

I'm trying to implement a cable combination in Qt as shown in the image below[image]

I used references to created a .qrc file and added all the images to the file and used the method like QImage.load("\cond.png"); and this is working. Now I want to implement this image combinations like layers loading on one another like:[image]

and [image]

should give me image like [image]

I want to implement my code by combining two image files at the same time one over the other or like layer over layer. Need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paint your images on a widget using `QPainter`:

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawImage(0, 0, QImage(":/1.png"));
    painter.drawImage(0, 0, QImage(":/2.png"));
}
```

But you should have images with trasparency to get what you want (all images in your example have white background).